# Create array of empty subarrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array of `n` number of distinct empty subarrays.

Is this the best way?

```
Array.new(n){ [] }
```

It was as follows, but I modified after reading comments:

```
Array.new(n){ |_| [] }
```

I tried:

```
Array.new(n, [])
```

but it creates an array with all the subarrays being the same object, which I do not want.

Comment: Another way: `n.times.map { |_| [] }`

Comment: Slightly more succinct: `Array.new(n){[]}`

Comment: Smells like _XY problem_. Maybe you need [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)?

Comment: @Neddy: Note also that if you have subarrays - empty or not - the "parent" array is not empty.

Comment: As indicated by @Aetherus's comment, if a block makes no use of values passed to it there is no need to define block variables.

Comment: "an empty array of empty sub arrays" is a self-contradiction. An empty array contains nothing.

Comment: You have not made clear at all whether "an array with all the sub arrays being the same object" is wanted or not.

Comment: @sawa doesn't _"But"_ imply that it is unwanted?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've modified the question for clarity. @Aetherus Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: @Stefan It may very weakly imply that, but too weak to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.new(n) { [] }` is totally fine!
The block ensures that a new instance of Array is created `n` times. As you pointed out, you would otherwise reference the same object (instance of Array) `n` times.

Comment: This is what I am going with, I wasn't sure if there was a more correct way to do this, but it appears not. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

All the proposed method to get this array `[[], [], [],...]` works fine:

```
Array.new(n, []) # the best, 20 times faster
Array.new(n){ [] }
n.times.map { [] }
```

The first is the fastest, so the best, but works strangely (see next).

> it created an array with all the sub arrays being the same object

If i get the point, you mean that whit the methods described happens what follows:

```
a = Array.new(5, [])
p a # => [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
p a.map { |e| e.object_id} # => [70189488740180, 70189488740180, 70189488740180, 70189488740180, 70189488740180]]
```

The object is the same, so if you try to fill subarrays with values, all of the subarrays assume the same value (replication):

```
a[0][0] = 10
p a # => [[10], [10], [10], [10], [10]]
```

To avoid this don't pass a default value, but map to empty array instead:

```
a = Array.new(5).map{ |e| [] }
p a # => [[], [], [], [], []]
```

Or pass the block

```
a = Array.new(5){ [] }
a = 5.times.map { [] }
```

Now each subarray is an independent object:

```
p a.map { |e| e.object_id} # => [70253023825640, 70253023825620, 70253023825600, 70253023825580, 70253023825560]
```

And if you insert some values there is no replication:

```
a[0][0] = 10
a[1][0] = 20
p a # => [[10], [20], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Why use `map` when you can simply pass a block to `new` as shown in the beginning?

Comment: @Stefan Ooops! Edit. Thanks. But I'm still not sure about what's the OP issue.

Comment: The original question was _"is there a better way than Array.new(n){ |_| [] }"_, so the OP probably just wanted to know if there is a shorthand syntax to create an array of empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It work for me.

```
  n = 15
  arr = Array.new(n)
  arr.map!{ |x| x = [] }
```

Now, putting value in the array.

```
arr[0][0] = 10 
arr[5][0] = 50
p arr # => [[10], [], [], [], [], [50], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: The assignment in `x = []` is superfluous, you just need `arr.map!{ [] }`. Which is merely `Array.new(n) { [] }` on two lines.